# Which Rails component is in charge of parsing the input from `date_select`?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
<%= date_select :person, :birth_date %>
```

Creates a params hash like so:

```
{'person' => {'birth_date(1i)' => '2008', 'birth_date(2i)' => '11', 'birth_date(3i)' => '22'}}
```

Which can be passed to a model instance. What Rails component handles converting this input into a Date passed to the setter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These "**multiparameter attributes**" (as called in Rails) are converted back to the single value during attribute assignment, i.e. during `Model.new` or `Model.update_attributes`, etc. method calls.

The relevant code can be found in the `AttributeAssignment` module of `ActiveRecord`, in the **[`assign_multiparameter_attributes` method](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb#L43)**. Quoting from its documentation string:

> Instantiates objects for all attribute classes that needs more than one constructor parameter. This is done by calling `new` on the column type or aggregation type (through composed_of) object with these parameters.
>
> So having the pairs `written_on(1) = "2004"`, `written_on(2) = "6"`, `written_on(3) = "24"`, will instantiate `written_on` (a date type) with `Date.new("2004", "6", "24")`.
>
> You can also specify a typecast character in the parentheses to have the parameters typecasted before they're used in the constructor. Use `i` for `Fixnum` and `f` for `Float`. If all the values for a given attribute are empty, the attribute will be set to `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

The Ruby module responsible for processing dates is `ActiveSupport`, specifically, the extensions on the `DateTime` modules which are built into Ruby.

If you're asking about the select box specifically within the HTML, that would be the `ActionView` helper methods, which renders a select box for `date_select`.

Hope this answers your question.